# Neovim sudo commands history file?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm using neovim and the history file is called "main.shada". However when I run the editor in sudo mode the list of previous commands is different; meaning they are stored in different files. I have tried searching online, even in the file explorer and I can't find this particular file. Where is the file is located, what is it called?

Comment: In the future, consider using the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim and NeoVim.

Answer (score 0):

When you run NeoVim under sudo, it will store its data (including history data) under **root**'s home directory (typically `/root`).

So the file should still be named `main.shada`, but it lives in a directory under `/root/.local/share/nvim/shada/` instead of the respective one in your home directory.

One recommendation is to *avoid* using the `sudo` command directly with a text editor such as NeoVim. Instead, use the `sudoedit` command (or `sudo -e`), which will make a copy of the file you want to edit with permissions that allow you to read/write to it, then open your editor as the non-root user, and finally overwrite it once you save the file back and close the editor. That way, the instance of NeoVim is running under your regular user and it will use your normal NeoVim configuration and plug-ins, and also store shada information such as the history under your normal user's shada directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the default location of `shade-file` (history) to fix the location of this file by:

```
set shada+='1000,n/opt/my.shada
```

don't forget to give the user permission to this file:

```
sudo chown username:username /opt/my.shada
```

if you want more history line change `1000` by a big number